# compile testing library does not compile static method of interface (Java 8)

Tags: java, java-8, annotation-processor, google-compile-testing

One of the feature of Java 8 is the capability to add static method to interface. I'm working on java library based on annotation processor, named [Kripton Persistence Library](http://github.com/xcesco/kripton).

I'm using the google [compile testing library](https://github.com/google/compile-testing). When I'm trying to test compilation of the following interface:

```
public interface AppDataSource {

    static void execute(DaoPerson daoPerson) {
        daoPerson.insert(new Person());
    }
}
```

With a code like the following:

```
ImmutableList<JavaFileObject> generated = com.google.testing.compile.Compiler.javac()
                    .compile(sourcesPhase1).generatedSourceFiles();
```

I obtain the following error:

```
sqlite/feature/transition/AppDataSource.java:29: error: modifier static not allowed here
    static void execute(DaoPerson daoPerson) {
```

The full code is available on:

https://github.com/xcesco/kripton/tree/v5.x/kripton-processor/src/test/java/sqlite/feature/transition

What am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your compiler, it may be using the version below java8.

The static methods are introduced in java8 and if your compiler uses java8 then you will not get error while compilation.

If you installed java8 version and if your compiler using the below versions rather than java8 then you will get compilation errors as follows.

**static interface methods are not supported in -source 1.7
        static void execute() {
                              ^
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable static interface methods)**

or 

**Static methods are allowed in interfaces only at source level 1.8 or above**

Please check the version used by your compiler and correct it.

Comment: Thank. After check, I found that in project there was a reference to an old tool.jar. Updated tool.jar to version 8, everything went ok.